# How to access SQL server tables from linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

**How do we query a SQL server table which is in SQL Server Management Studio from linux terminal?**

I am trying to store the output of count(*) of a table in a variable.

```
count=`sqlplus -s ${username}/${password}@${database_name} <<END
SELECT COUNT(*) from tablename; 
exit;
END`
echo $count
```

The error that I get is Bad Substitution. I tried removing the $ but then it gives me the error sqlplus command not found.

Comment: `sqlplus` is the Oracle SQL command line utility so doesn't work with Microsoft SQL Server which has `sqlcmd` for the command line. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools to install the SQL Server command line tools on Linux.

Comment: @Brian you should make that an answer.

Comment: YES, sqlcmd is the right command to be used.

Comment: If through sqlcmd, still how will I store the output of a count of a table in a shell script variable?